# Why can't I connect to a private VPN Network set up on my local machine?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, internet-connection, pptp, private-network

I am connected through a router to the internet. In Windows 7 Enterprise I set up a private VPN server to connect to, but I can only connect to the default gateway and no further.

Everything is on DHCP and no static IPs are assigned.

**"No Internet Access"** is written in *Connections*:

[image]

My Edimax router is configured to forward TCP port 1723 and UDP port 1723 to internal IP **192.168.2.100**:

[image]

**Note:** my VPN is set to automatic:

[image]

What must I do to grant outside access to the private VPN tunnel?

**UPDATE:** RAS (Dial In) Interface has disappeared from connections but service is running but i cannot connect no matter what. I have tried many things. Is RAS critical component to connect to VPN?

[image]

Comment: This is confusing.  Are you trying to set up a VPN server to accept incoming connections, or dial out to a VPN server located someplace else?

Comment: To accept incoming connections to VPN server i have setup.

Answer (score 1):

Test your connection from a device outside your network - many routers will not let local devices 'loop back' via their public address to other devices on the local network.

Comment: I could connect from local device.